# Cannot access ServiceHost methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have a Silverlight project that uses a WCF service that I created.  My problem is that in my WCF service, I created a ServiceHost but VS2010 doesn't seem to recognize the instance of my object (underlines the svHost).  Below is the code for my service.

```
using System;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace userIO.Web
{
     [ServiceContract]
     public class CoordsService
     {
         [OperationContract]
         public double xDir();
         [OperationContract]
         public double yDir();
         [OperationContract]
         public String keyPressed();

         public class Coords : CoordsService
         {
             public double xDir { get; set; }
             public double yDir { get; set; }
             public String keyPressed { get; set; }
         }

         ServiceHost svHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Coords), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
         BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
         svHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(CoordsService), binding, "");
         svHost.Open();
     }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile - you cannot have statements outside a method. The last two lines (AddServiceEndpoint and Open) should give you a build error. Can you post your correct code?

Comment: I posted on SO because I wasn't able to compile it.  Wasn't sure how to fix those particular lines.

Comment: If you're using SL and VS, you should add a new "Silverlight-Enabled WCF Service". That will have the boilerplate for the service which can be consumed by SL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ServiceContract should decorate an interface (a contract).  The ServiceHost should host an instance of this interface and be outside the same service that it's hosting.  At least I've only seen it done in this way.

The basic structure is:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
     [OperationContract]
     void DoSomething(Data data);
}

[DataContract]
public class Data
{
     [DataMember]
     int Num {get;set;}
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public void DoSomething(Data data)
    {  // do something }
}

// run in any other kind of app, console, win service, winform/wpf
static void Main()
{
         ServiceHost svHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8080"));
         BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
         svHost.AddServiceEndpoint(binding, "");
         svHost.Open();

}
```

An even easier solution to get your service up and running in VS2010 is to just create the service in a new WCF Service template.  Take out their demo code, put in your own code for the servicecontract interface and the implementation service, then choose debug -> run and VS2010 will host the service for you without having to create an external app to run the service.  Will also let you send data to the service to test out the code and the return values of your wcf functions in their simple winforms app.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up WCF.  However, can I still access ServiceHosts from a class in a .svc.cs file?

Comment: to my knowledge and hosting a WCF service in iis, you want to only put in the svc.cs the info about what service name for iis to host.  If that's what you're getting at when you mention svc.cs file.

Comment: The whole concept of a service and wcf is to host the service somewhere external to the code/client using it.  That's the point of SOA, the work is done somewhere else, somewhere external to the application who wants to consume it.  So you'll need to host your service in something other than the app you're wanting to use that consumes it.